# Intermediate results from SatisfiabilityInstances

Tags: logic, monitoring

I have a large logical expression, with roughly 100 boolean variables. I am interested in the solution with the smallest numbers of `True`. It seems there is no such option, thus I use `SatisfiabilityInstances`, searching for a large number of instances:

`sf = SatisfiabilityInstances[FinalExpression, BooleanVariables[FinalExpression], 100000, Method -> "SAT"];`

Afterwards, I search manually for the instance with the smallest number of True.

---

**Question1**: Is there a way to obtain the solution with smallest number of True in a more efficient way?

**Question2**: Is there a way to monitor the intermediate results of `SatisfiabilityInstances`? For instance, that it periodically prints how many solutions its already found (and its truth values)

Answer (score 2):

Q1 - probably not - this problem is hard. Here's another way of looking at it: I've converted the expression to DNF which may take an unacceptable amount of time and memory on large expressions. DNF is an OR of brackets containing only a string of ANDs. More technically, DNF is a disjunction of clauses containing only conjunctions. As such, with a DNF form we need only find the bracket with the smallest number of positive terms (those that don't have negation).

We set those positive terms to `True` and the rest to `False`. If there is a bracket with no positive terms then we can satisfy the expression assigning all variables `False`.

```
(* test function *)
SeedRandom[1];
fn = BooleanConvert[BooleanFunction[RandomInteger[2^15], Array[x, 15]], "DNF"];
vars = BooleanVariables[fn];

(* Get the positive terms (no nots allowed *)
getTrues[expr_] := BooleanVariables[expr /. Not[__] :> True];

(* Find the DNF bracket with the smallest number of positive terms *)
smallestTrExpr = MinimalBy[fn /. Or -> List, Length@*getTrues][[1]];

(* Create an assignment *)
result = Thread[getTrues[smallestTrExpr] -> True]
(* RESULT: {x[12] -> True, x[13] -> True} *)

Print["Min inputs needed true: " <> ToString@Length[result]]

(* RESULT: Min inputs needed true: 2 *)

(* Try it out and set all other terms to false *)
FullSimplify[fn /. result] /. Thread[vars -> False]
(* RESULT: True *)
```

Comment: That's a very nice way to think about the problem. Now unfortunatly, the translation to DNF takes long time for large expressions, but that is a different problem. Thank you!

Comment: @MarioKrenn another way I've thought is to convert the boolean expression into a one-zero integer linear programming (ILP) problem and add an objective to minimize the sum of variables. The trouble is the expression is probably not easy to convert.